# Linkedin API Connections and Messages php Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, api, get, linkedin-api

I am integrating the linkedin API (PHP and Javascript - Seperate prototypes) in my website. I am unable to access the connections of the logged in user via this GET method

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections?format=json
```

it gives the error "403 forbidden". Even if i try it in the console, it gives the same error. Which means I cant access the connection request. So what am I doing wrong? I have granted all the possible permissions that my linkedin app page is showing that is

```
r_emailaddress rw_company_admin r_emailaddress w_share
```

I can access basic profile, email address. But not the connections.

On the other hand whenever I want to access this link:

```
https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting
```

I get "Access Denied" written on the page and nothing else. What is all this strictness for? And what is the error on my GET request for connections?